# accessing a Dynamic ng-repeat using selenium and ngWebDriver

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a web interface. Some frames are based on Angular JS.
I am trying to access an ng-repeat inside dynamic columns.

Here is a snippet of my DOM :

```
 <div class="containCol__col column-animation col0" ng-repeat="column 
 in sbCtrl.SlideboardStore.columns track by` 
 sbCtrl.getUniqueColumnId(column)" column-id="emptydata" ng-class=" 
 {'enabled': column.showNewCardInput, 'containCol__col__collapsed': 
 column.isCollapsed}" style="opacity: 1;">
```

So here you can see that the ng-repeat is dynamic and depends on Column ID:

```
ng-repeat="column in sbCtrl.SlideboardStore.columns track 
bysbCtrl.getUniqueColumnId(column)
```

Here is what I am trying to do in Selenium :

```
WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(ByAngular.withRootSelector("#application-container").exactRepeater());
```

Now my problems is how can I find the selector for the repeater as it's Dynamic, I thought of selecting the column first but as it's not a frame I don't know ho to deal with this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Hello guys just found the answer, I have removed the dynamic part from the selector ans selected the column through an Xpath and it works like a charm.

```
WebElement repeater = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(ByAngular.withRootSelector("#application-container").exactRepeater("column in sbCtrl.SlideboardStore.columns"));
```